# Unable to figure out why 'hover' is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have a simple **HTML** which goes like this :-

```
 <div id="divEntity" class="col-md-2 noPadding align-right">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEntity" CssClass="labelText"></asp:Label>
                <span id="showEntity" class="trigger trigger-caret"></span>
                <ul id="ulMenu" class="ulMenuParent contextMenu-style lstTransactions">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindCustomerGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.lblContacts)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindInvoiceGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.Invoices)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindProjectGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.ManageProposals)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindProposalGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.Proposals)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindPurchaseOrderGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.PurchaseOrders)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindWorkOrderGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.WorkOrder)%></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I need to show the **menu-list** i.e. the `ulMenu` on hovering `showEntity` .I am unable to figure out why my `hover` is not working . Had tried `on-hover` , `mouseover` but didn't get the expected result. When I put my **script** in `console` and then run , hopefully the `ulMenu` gets open but that too inconsistently . Experts here , Kindly help !!

**SCRIPT**

This is the `mouseover` event i had tried but no luck :-

```
$("#showEntity").on('mouseover', function () {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').show().offset({ top: offset.top + 8, left: offset.left - 110 });

}).on('mouseout', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').hide();
});
```

This is the `hover` event i had tried but no luck :-

```
$("#showEntity").hover(function () {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').show().offset({ top: offset.top + 8, left: offset.left - 110 });
},function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').hide();      
});
```

**CSS**

```
 #divEntity ul#ulMenu {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
 }


.trigger {
     background-image: url('../Image/p7PM_dark_south.gif');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: right center;
     font-size: 1.1em;
 }

.trigger-caret:hover {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    border-color: #adadad;
 }

.trigger-caret {
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 15px !important;
 }
```

**FYI : No nodes in the HTML here are getting dynamically generated. Using jQuery 1.9.0 .**

Comment: what about a fiddle? :D

Comment: `#showEntity` has no content, no width, no height ---> no `hover` possible.

Comment: well it has actually , `trigger` and `trigger-caret` classes are making that span look like an `image` . I will update my CSS Part to make you understand better .

Comment: If you like include this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c7r3ow53/10/) in your question. The image-link is broken, so `#showEntity` is very small, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem will be that you may not have loaded the jQuery. Can you double check you've added it to your page, and initialised it.

I put your code in a fiddle, and the hover works.

http://jsfiddle.net/e3vydbup/

```js
$("#showEntity").hover(function () {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').show().offset({ top: offset.top + 8, left: offset.left - 110 });
},function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').hide();      
});
```

```css
 #divEntity ul#ulMenu {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
 }


.trigger {
     background-image: url('../Image/p7PM_dark_south.gif');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: right center;
     font-size: 1.1em;
 }

.trigger-caret:hover {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    border-color: #adadad;
 }

.trigger-caret {
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 15px !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divEntity" class="col-md-2 noPadding align-right">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEntity" CssClass="labelText"></asp:Label>
                <span id="showEntity" class="trigger trigger-caret"></span>
                <ul id="ulMenu" class="ulMenuParent contextMenu-style lstTransactions">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindCustomerGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.lblContacts)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindInvoiceGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.Invoices)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindProjectGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.ManageProposals)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindProposalGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.Proposals)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindPurchaseOrderGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.PurchaseOrders)%></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BindWorkOrderGrid();"><%=(Resources.Resource.WorkOrder)%></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```